# Opening mail from IMAP with no risk for the user

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm building a website for an association. Its aim is to, out of other thing, provide an easy mail manager to communicate with the member, stored in a database. This database is always up to date as it used to manage the members status, contributions, etc. That's why I want to use a integrated "custom" webmail instead of, for instance, RoundCube.

So the user can send mail from this website using the association mail address and SwiftMailer, and would like to be able to check the corresponding inbox from this very website.

I found out that there is a php IMAP extension, which seems to fill my needs, I can fetch eMails from the IMAP server. Though, I am affraid to create a security breach in the user's computer by making possible to display, for instance, spams, or malware contained in attachements. As I couldn't find anything on the internet, and I suppose displaying only text eMail would work (but it's not as user friendly) **what would be the rules to build a secure eMail reader from an IMAP server that tends to be spammed?**

Comment: Protip: try to have a "spamfilter" on the IMAP server that sends mail to a "junk" folder, and an option for employees to tag mail adresses as "junk", so IT could look at it and mark it to auto-move to junk folders on arrival, and always intergrate a blocklist!

Comment: @Lighty You're right! I'm hosted by an extrenal company on a dedicated server that already provides an anti-spam. From what I understood (but you may tell me wrong, if it's impossible) the anti spam is located before my server, so that spams can't reach it in the first place.
But thanks for the advice, I'll integrate that "Move to Junk" button.

Answer (score 2):

By controlling the presentation layer, you may **display a confirmation pop-up** before redirecting to the target URLs. While requesting confirmation, the pop-up would highlight the target domain and include a reminder about dangers related to malicious websites

Comment: That is a good idea! I'll keep it mind, even though I pretty much gave on this idea a few weeks ago; I managed to use RoundCube with a homemade plugin that fitted my needs quite enough, and with less **LESS** efforts, and more security.